# Problem in connecting with Wi-Fi networks

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I am having problem with my WiFi connection.

Initially all is right.

This is my panel

[image]

This is the pop up menu

[image]

After certain time the net connection is gone

Then I disable and re enable WiFi as it works sometimes. But now even the Wi-Fi networks disappear.

[image]

[image]

Then I reboot my computer. Now everything is back to normal. My WiFi network auto connects.

[image]

How to fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

The output of my terminal command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

is as given below:

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.     RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b736]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the ant_sel parameter is available in 16.04 and there is no real need to download anything

Comment: @Jeremy31: Imho it'd be better to add an appropriate answer (or edit edit an existing) to clarify that.